# Custom Nagios script not firing

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, nagios

Recently we've been experiencing a lot of spam hitting our servers causing `apache` to topple over.  To tackle this we've installed `nagios` to notify us/run some restart commands if the issue arises. Notifications function fine, but the restart scripts just wont kick in.  We've taken the following steps:

- Created our restart script located: `/usr/share/nagios3/plugins/eventhandlers/restart_apache`
- Tested and ran via `./restart_apache CRITICAL SOFT 3` - can confirm the script works
- Defined the command: `/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg`

```
define command{
        command_name restart-apache
        command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/restart_apache $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICESTATETYPE$ $SERVICEATTEMPT$
}
```

- Applied the command to fire when current load notifications run: `/etc/nagios3/conf.d/localhost_nagios2.cfg`

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             Current Load
        check_command                   check_load!5.0!4.0!3.0!10.0!6.0!4.0
        event_handler                   restart-apache
        }
```

- We've set the script to write to a text file when performing a restart, but nothing is happening (and apache stays down) - so something is not right. Any direction is much appreciated!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should make sure that handlers are enabled and logging in your nagios.cfg

```
enable_event_handlers=1
log_event_handlers=1
```

then try to tail your nagios logs (in my case `/var/spool/nagios/nagios.log` )
and wait for your event, you should see the handler being executed or failing

```
tail -f /var/spool/nagios/nagios.log | egrep HANDLER
...
[1271946604] SERVICE EVENT HANDLER: $HOST:$SERVICE:CRITICAL:HARD:3:$YOUR_RESTART_HANDLER
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I can confirm the script is now firing - however, we need to run `sudo service apache2 stop` - but this just wont fire from the script. Any idea?

Comment: Make sure nagios is allowed to run that command via sudo, without a password and without requiring a TTY.